# how to get the value of other child node element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to get a the value `<abc-value>abc</abc-value>` of other child node elment from current node.

Example:

```
<root>
  <child1>
     <abc-value>abc</abc-value>
  </child>
  <child2>
     <attribute name=def>def</def-value>
  </child2>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="child2" match="attribute">
   child1 value is: <xsl:value-of select="../abc-value"/>
   child2 value is: <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

All i am trying to do is, from child2 template match, I am calling the value of child1 element `<abc-value>abc</abc-value>`.

Exptected out:

Child1 value is: abc

Child2 value is: def

Comment: After your last edit, your XML is no longer well-formed. Specifically `<attribute name=def>def</def-value>`. Also, you might be confusing yourself with the `match` and `name` attributes in `xsl:template`. If you truly need to use a named template, choose a name that's not the same as one of the input elements. This will make it easier to understand.

Comment: It wasn't well formed before the last edit either: The close tag of child1 can't be child.   And why name the new element 'attribute'?  And why keep extending this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:template name="child2" match="attribute">
   child1 value is: <xsl:value-of select="../../child1/abc-value" />
   child2 value is: <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Update: based on the edit to your question:

- The template now matches the `<attribute>` element.
- Since the current node for the template (the `<attribute>` element) is deeper than before, the select expression for the child1 value is changed to use an additional `../`.

Comment: Right, +1, but please close `xsl:value-of` statements -- too small for SO to let me to fix.

Comment: When i use it, it get the following error: XPTY0020: Cannot select a node here: the context item is an atomic value

Comment: updated child2 node with the new element `<attribute`

Comment: @phani: As written, your template can only match an element (whether `<child2>` or `<attribute>`), not an atomic value. An atomic value is e.g. a number or a string (not an element or a text node). So you must be using a different match pattern than what you showed in your answer. Show us what you're actually doing and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Larsh you are correct, i figured it out it was my template syntax error.